# Solve equations 1) $z^4 = i$) and $(z+1)^n +(z-1)^n = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to solve those 2 equations.

1. $z^4 = i$
2. $(z+1)^n +(z-1)^n=0$

I got solutions, but I am not sure that they are correct. Could you please verify it ?

> $z^4 = i$
> $|z|^4(\cos4\phi + \sin4\phi) = i$
> This implies, $|z|^4\cos4\phi = 0 $ and $|z|^4\sin4\phi= 1$
> We have two cases, either $|z|^4 = \sin4\phi=1$ or $|z|^4 \neq \sin4\phi$
> I found the solution for the first case, which is $\cos\phi = \frac{1}{8}\pi$

What is about second case?

Second exercise:

> $\begin{align}
> \left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^n&=-1\\\\
> &=e^{i(2k+1)\pi}
> \end{align}$

I don't understand why is it equal to $e^{i(2k+1)\pi}$.

Comment: These are two questions posted as one. And $(z+1)^n+(z-1)^n$  is not an equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint...
For the first one you should have four solutions, which you can obtain by writing $i$ in exponential form:
$$i=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\cdot2\pi)}$$

Similarly for the second one, write $$-1=e^{i(\pi+k\cdot2\pi)}$$

Comment: David, I don't see why are there 4 solutions.

Comment: Please explain this answer more thoroughly

Comment: there are many online sources which will explain this, such as https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Forms.aspx.

Comment: Also, a polynomial equation of order $n$ must have $n$ (possibly complex) roots. See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra

Comment: David, I have not figured it out. Please explain this to me.

Comment: what is it you're not sure about?

Comment: please bear in mind this is not a homework-solving site